# How to rescue an encrypted LUKS partition that was partially modified by a Windows tool?

Tags: lvm, partition, data-recovery, luks

On a system with dual boot, the Windows tool [Dell SupportAssist](https://www.dell.com/en-us/lp/support-assist-for-pcs) started to modify partitions now I ended up with a broken Linux installation.

The Linux installation is/was [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) with an encrypted LUKS partition and before applying a week-old backup I thought that there might be a change of rescuing some data.

A live distribution still found the partitions and [`testdisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) claimed that was able to identify its boundaries.

It seems that there's still some data accessible:

```bash
$ cryptsetup luksDump
LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          3
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           3ebdbc55-c283-4b33-89f6-b254057db9d0
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)

Data segments:
  0: crypt
    offset: 16777216 [bytes]
    length: (whole device)
    cipher: aes-xts-plain64
    sector: 512 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
    Key:        512 bits
    Priority:   normal
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
    Cipher key: 512 bits
    PBKDF:      argon2i
    Time cost:  7
    Memory:     1048576
    Threads:    4
    Salt:       a5 ff f5 ae 21 38 4f 44 4b af 26 fb bd b5 15 7f 
                41 dd 86 4a c1 41 7f 2c 35 f7 52 0b b8 ff 3b a4 
    AF stripes: 4000
    AF hash:    sha512
    Area offset:32768 [bytes]
    Area length:258048 [bytes]
    Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
    Hash:       sha512
    Iterations: 187513
    Salt:       0d 92 31 9c ae 3c a7 d1 aa 04 5f 37 e5 ff 6f 4e 
                a7 4f 37 3f a5 0c 2c a4 db 31 69 06 52 91 79 16 
    Digest:     13 3c 62 0f 06 17 be 9b e5 da 86 05 d5 fb 39 ad 
                d8 e2 2f a5 fd 8f 14 55 50 c5 c1 73 e9 e6 84 76 
                86 e2 c3 f1 c2 ef 72 c4 bf f5 42 0a 8f 43 5a 0e 
                cd a9 2b c4 70 de 0d b8 d5 06 40 2b a6 4e 10 64
```

but I'm getting an error message when trying to mount it (`WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/crypt has size of 1985102877 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 3585935360 sectors. Was device resized?`):

```bash
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p4 crypt
Enter passphrase for /dev/nvme0n1p4:
$ sudo vgchange -ay 
  WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/crypt has size of 1985102877 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 3585935360 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG vgubuntu have changed sizes.
  device-mapper: reload ioctl on  (252:2) failed: Invalid argument
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "vgubuntu" now active
```

This error pops up on all commands:

```bash
$ sudo vgdisplay
  WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/crypt has size of 1985102877 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 3585935360 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG vgubuntu have changed sizes.
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vgubuntu
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <1.67 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              437736
  Alloc PE / Size       437736 / <1.67 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               5v0f8R-w1Qg-SBI2-Ozzb-0f1z-aCML-yyDsxq

$ sudo vgchange -ay --activationmode partial
  PARTIAL MODE. Incomplete logical volumes will be processed.
  WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/crypt has size of 1985102877 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 3585935360 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG vgubuntu have changed sizes.
  device-mapper: reload ioctl on  (252:2) failed: Invalid argument
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "vgubuntu" now active

$ sudo lvscan
  WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/crypt has size of 1985102877 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 3585935360 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG vgubuntu have changed sizes.
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vgubuntu/swap' [<41.04 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/vgubuntu/root' [<1.63 TiB] inherit
```

I thought that maybe resetting the boundaries might help but it didn't:

```bash
$ sudo lvreduce -L -1M /dev/vgubuntu/root
  WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/crypt has size of 1985102877 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 3585935360 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG vgubuntu have changed sizes.
  Rounding size to boundary between physical extents: 0   .
  New size (427230 extents) matches existing size (427230 extents).
```

So maybe that wasn't a good idea on my side.

This is how the structure in `testdisk` looks like:

[image: Disk /dev/nvme0n1 - 2048 GB / 1907 GiB - CHS 1953514 64 32 Partition Start End Size in sectors >P MS Data 2048 1085439 1083392 [Recovery] P EFI System 1085440 1290239 204800 [EFI System Partition] [NO NAME] D MS Data 403359745 405266432 1906688 D MS Data 405266432 407173119 1906688 D MS Data 405676033 407175168 1499136 D MS Data 407175168 408674303 1499136 P Linux filesys. data 408674304 412581887 3907584 P Linux filesys. data 412581888 2397717532 1985135645]

This is how its intense scan looks like:

[image: testdisk intensive scan result]

This is how the structure in DMDE looks like:

[image: partition overview of DMDE]

[image: screenshot of DMDE]

Any advice on how to proceed to try rescuing the data?

Comment: simple task, restore from backup

Comment: "After booting to SuppportAssist OS Recovery you will see a Tutorial.
Exit the tutorial and click on the repair tile on the home page.
Follow the onscreen prompts and at the end of the process restart back to the main OS".  https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000187311/install-of-supportassist-os-recovery-causing-data-loss

Comment: Hello @djdomi, you might want to read the second sentence. ;)

Comment: Thank you @GregAskew, but unfortunately this won't recover the lost data on Linux partitions.

Comment: If nothing was overwritten aside from the partition metadata, perhaps you can create  two duplicate disks, one using your broken disk and the other using your backup and restore the partition table from that which hopefully will fix the sector size for the devices used by the physical volume, and then see if it still produces the error. I haven't used the tool you mentioned, but most tools such as parted support restoring the partition table from a backup and you may be able to get a clean partition table backup from your backup.

Comment: Hello @philipenix, some things were overriden as I realised too late that the Dell SupportAssist was resizing partitions and writing data to them. If only the partition table would be changed, fixing it with `testdisk` would be enough but in this case it didn't help unfortunately. I'm sure that the partition being encrypted adds to that too.

Comment: I'm not sure what was written but I think your best bet is to fix the disks/PVs that are members of the VG in order to see if resolves the issue. Resize/fix the metadata of the affected partition and recreate the PV.

Comment: @philipenix can you explain further what I should do exactly? Unfortunate I'm not very good with knowing the relations between all this and I surely want to avoid any further issues.

Comment: It's possible the tool wrote over new partitions without clearing any data or meta data. So crafting the original partition size would restore parts not written to. But having used lvm commands would already cause damages (in addition to what the Windows tool might have done in the middle of the "shortened" partition).

Comment: These two UL SE Q/A might help you (the goal is to locate the LUKS header or a backup of it (LUKS2)): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/706070/restore-a-luks-partition-that-was-overwritten-by-pvcreate/706071#706071 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741404/overwritten-luks-with-a-partition-table/741850#741850 .

Answer (score 2):

Keep calm, don't apply changes on testdisk further.

1. Get an USB Hard Drive **(important)**
2. Clone entire disk to USB HDD with [dd](https://linuxhint.com/dd_command_linux/) command
3. Then, attempt to rescue marked partition below **in the USB HDD**

[image: Last detected missing partition]

If you're lucky, you could mount and get the data out from the USB HDD. Otherwise, repeat step 2 but upper than the marked partition in trial & error manner, one-by-one, and hope for the best.

> **Edit:** The reason why I ask you to do this outside internal drive, because once you messed up the drive with testdisk, most likely first-most detected partition would be broken. Once broken, there is nothing we could do.